# Filling the fields needs to publish a web service to web

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is first time I am doing this, so I have a `ASP.NET 1.1` type web service, `asmx`.
And for testing by others in house, I want to publish it to a `VM.`
They have given me their VM name. it is `vm-testweb`
And in my project properties the project URL next to where there is Create Virtual Directory button is `http://localhost/MyWebService_ForTesting`

So now I right click on project and select Publish Web and this dialog comes up, From the info that I have how should I populate these fields?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change the Publish method to File System

[image]

Comment: Thanks, then how about the Target Location field? How to populate that?

Comment: You should create a New folder for publishing your website, and enter the path of that folder. So there you will find your published site.